# Golang concurrent http requests have to wait for each other

Tags: post, go, client, goroutine

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time I really can't see the cause..
The thing is I am calling a goroutine n times, which has to leave some result in a channel. This goroutines perform a post request to some website with a Client. The thing is that it looks like they have to wait for each other, since their times (the time for the function to finish) look like this in the output:
1s
2s
3s
5s
.
.

and so on; when they're supposed to run concurrently.

Here it goes the important pieces of the code.

First, the calling function. This is supposed to trigger a "getFlight" for every id, and keep gathering the information they return through the channel. postUrl and urlParams are pre-assigned variables, a string and a pointer, respectively. The copy of the client is simply cause I thought that using the same client could've been the reason for the serialization, but looks like not.

```
result := []types.Trip{}
c := make(chan types.Trip)
for _, id := range ids {
    client1 := *client
    client2 := &client1
    go getFlight(id, postUrl, urlParams, client2, c)
}
for range ids {
    result = append(result, <-c)
}

return result
```

And this is the part of getFlight where I make the http request. All the variables have been previously initialized.

```
func getFlight(id string, postUrl string, urlParams *url.Values, client*http.Client, c chan types.Trip)

var newTrip types.Trip
newTrip.Url = postUrl
newTrip.UrlParams = *urlParams


r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", myUrl, bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()))
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")

resp, err := client.Do(r)
if err != nil {
    return
}

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()
```

As I said, the output of getFlight time, for every thread, looks like this:

4.6196584s
5.8934936s
7.1387969s
8.3415495s
9.7005444s
11.078563s
12.1587691s
13.8861763s

There's just not any kind of concurrency, and I really don't know why... And all the functions are starting at the same time, just put a Println at the very beggining of getFlight and all where shown at the same time.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The problem is indeed when calling client.Do(r), I put the timers before and after the call, and I get the same timings (1s, 2s, 3s, 5s..), therefore there is where the threads are waiting for the previous thread to finish. The question is, why?

Comment: Set it to 16 but still have the same problem. Still, I said that all the functions are starting at the same time! thanks anyway

Comment: Even if GOMAXPROCS was 1, the requests wouldn't be serialized. Are you sure the remote server will accept more than 1 connection at a time?

Comment: that's my main guess... Is there a way to check that? :/

Comment: Indeed, changed the request for a GET to Google and it was all concurrent... Well, thank you, major problem haha!

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've read the issue more clearly - I apologise. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Just so you know, I solved it. It had something to do with the previous requests I had to do to get there (it's a scraping func, so like the "previous pages" to get to the current one with this post). They had to be done with the same client as this last one. So what I did was create a very new client for every post request, that will simulate the whole process including the previous requests. It doesn't add more execution time, since all the requests are concurrent. Thank you all!